# In geometry nodes: moving instances relative to one another in sequence, and with individual control of rotation

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, transform-orientation

I'm trying to rotate individual objects using GeomNodes. However I want to control how much each one rotates. Also every object should rotate with respect to the one in front in a vertebrae kind of way.

This is the start position:
[image: Starting position]

I have tried the following node arrangement:
[image: nodes-part1]
[image: nodes-part2]

This is the result. It works for the first two rotating cones, but for the last one not. it appears to be offset for some weird reason:

[image]

Comment: Not and answer, because geonodes might not be the right tool for the job. Have you tried using an armature? this kind of thing is what armatures and constraints are for, setting this up would only take a few seconds.

If not applicable, please explain what your end goal is.

Comment: Im using Geonodes bc I need them to rotate using a mathematical expresion that would be added after. With an armature is very simple, but to imput and extract the mathematical data would be very tedious manually (since I need to do it for different models) when I could potentially do it in geonodes...

Comment: You can control bones with expressions as well, using drivers.